# empty node in xsl file

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I am trying to transform XML using XSLT.  But whole node FKN-VERS  empty   . can any one suggest please ..
my xml-code is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Versions>
  <FirstVersion >
    <Element OriginalName="fin_Test" >
      <ElementClass Name="TEST"/>
      <ElementAttributes/>
    </Element>
    <Type Name="TEST" />
    <LifecycleState Name="OPe" Lifecycle="STANDARD" />
    <Predecessors>
      <Predecessor Variant="BASE_RETEST1" Revision="1"/>
    </Predecessors>

  </FirstVersion>
</Versions>
```

my xsl code for transformation is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:template match="/Versions[FirstVersion/Type/@Name='TEST']">
    <DATA>
      <xsl:attribute name="ID">10</xsl:attribute>
      <FKN-VERS>
        <FKN-VERS>
          <xsl:for-each select="  Versions/FirstVersion/Predecessors">
            <VERS-LABEL>
              <xsl:value-of select="concat(@Variant, ';',@Revision)"/>
            </VERS-LABEL>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </FKN-VERS>
      </FKN-VERS>
    </DATA>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<ID="10">
  <FKN-VERS>
    <FKN-VERS/>
  </FKN-VERS>
</DATA>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your `for-each` statement,

```
<xsl:for-each select="  Versions/FirstVersion/Predecessors">
```

to

```
<xsl:for-each select="FirstVersion/Predecessors/Predecessor">
```

because the current node will already be at a `Versions` element when the containing template matches and because you wish to iterate over `Predecessor` elements, not the containing `Predecessors` elements.

Comment: Are you now using `<xsl:for-each select="FirstVersion/Predecessors/Predecessor">` ? (Earlier versions of this answer had to be edited to reflect changes you made to the code in your question.)

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like your selection path starts one node too high up, and ends one node too high up. Try this:

```
<xsl:for-each select="FirstVersion/Predecessors/Predecessor">
   <VERS-LABEL>
       <xsl:value-of select="concat(@Variant, ';',@Revision)"/>
   </VERS-LABEL>
</xsl:for-each>
```